# Make an audio start/stop toggle on Android

Tags: android, android-music-player

I have looked everywhere about music on Android development. I have looked at the API but I didn't understand it. This is my code:

```
 Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.track1);
        mp.start();
       }           
});
```

How I can change it so that when I press the same button again it stops it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package com.my.testing;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestAndActivity extends Activity {

    public MediaPlayer mp = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mp == null) {
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestAndActivity.this, R.raw.track1);
                    mp.start();
                } else {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp = null;
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a syntax erro on else expected {

Comment: still getting the syntax error "syntax error on token else, { expected"

Comment: right got it to start and stop now once stopped it wont start again

Comment: right error "The final local variable mp cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"

Comment: if i just copy your code into a blank project exactly as it is it has errors next to mp thats says "Cannot refer to a non-final variable mp inside an inner class defined in a different 
 method" and gives a quick fix to put final in front of MediaPlayer mpif i put final it bring 2 errors up saying dead code and "Cannot refer.. error"

Comment: Please Check code now. I have write down the whole activity for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For fun you can define two identical buttons on the same place in your layout and make such trick...

```
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/media_player12"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/media_player" />    
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/mute12"
 android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:visibility="gone"
 android:clickable="false"
 android:src="@drawable/mute" />
```

and code...

```
    final ImageView s_on12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.media_player12);
    s_on12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.track1);
    mp.start();
            final ImageView s_off12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mute12);
            s_on12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            s_on12.setClickable(false);
            s_off12.setVisibility(1);
            s_off12.setClickable(true);
            s_off12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.stop();

                    s_on12.setVisibility(1);
                    s_on12.setClickable(true);
                    s_off12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    s_off12.setClickable(false);
                }
            });

        }
    });
```